# What is the scope of the word 'Ummah' according to Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, prophet-muhammad

Although this [question about Ummah](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/7570/what-does-ummah-mean-in-islam) asks for definition of Ummah, I am interested to know the scope of 'Ummah' does it mean the entire Humanity, based on following hadith

> "By Him in Whose hand is the soul of Muhammad, any Jew or Christian
>   amongst this Ummah (nation) who hears about me but does not affirm his
>   belief in that with which I have been sent and dies in this state (of
>   disbelief), he shall be but one of the inhabitants of Hellfire."
>
> [Narrated by Muslim](http://www.sunnah.com/muslim/1/293)

Since the Prophet (pbuh) was sent to the entire humanity doesn't it mean that, Ummah includes entire humanity?

Comment: Subhanallaah... I did not know this hadeeth. Do you think you can give me the hadeeth number to check this out?

Comment: do verify the correct translation , the above might be wrong. I have updated the arabic source, @itsols

Comment: The entire humanity, including present day non-Muslims are in the ummah of Prophet Muhammad (SAWS), regardless of whether they believe in him or not.

Answer (score 1):

### **Ummah in the Quran**

It is used for non-Muslims as well. Here, the purpose of Ummah is a large group of people that have the same language or religion or have the same geographical land.

This word (Ummah) has come 65 times in the holy Qur’an (Singular and plural). Its meaning in the Qur'an is people (Surah Al-Baqarah(2):213) and likewise humans who have religious union(3:110, 2:143). Frequently, it has come in the narrations as Ummatl-Muhammad or Ummati or Ummam, and it means a school or group that follows a prophet. Ummam also is applied as prior kinfolk and nations that Allah has sent them a prophet.

**Different dimensions of the concept of Ummah in the Islamic culture (in short):**

> 1: Islamic Ummah, successor of the prior Ummam
>
> 2: Ummah as the heir of the earth
>
> 3: Ummah and Sunnah
>
> 4: Amrel-Ma'ruf wa Nahi Anel Monkar (أمر المعروف و النهی عن المنکر )

**According to another definition, In accordance with Sura Al-Anbiya verses 92-94:**

The Arabic word /ummah/, according to Mufradat by Raqib, means any group or nation that a common cause joins them to each other, such as being common in religion and creed, being in the same time or Age, and being in one definite place, whether this unity is optional or non-optional.
Some commentators have considered the phrase: ‘single Ummah’, mentioned here, as ‘a single religion’.
Some others have said that the objective meaning of ‘Ummah’, in this verse, is the whole mankind in all ages and times.

---

**Sources:**

- [www.al-islam.org](http://www.al-islam.org/enlightening-commentary-light-holy-quran-vol-10/section-7-righteous-shall-inherit-earth)
- [wiki.ahlolbait.com](http://wiki.ahlolbait.com/index.php/%D8%A7%D9%85%D9%91%D8%AA) (in Farsi)